# getting back to old commit in github vscode flutter

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I want to take old commit's code but, I don't want to change my repo, just mycodes from github to vscode.
[image]

Comment: `git checkout f6e83a1` to get a detached HEAD

Comment: yep, I just ruined my codes, sorry I am new, can you provide me how should I write ? "git checkout f6e83a1 [master---> this is branch name]" or Idk

Comment: read the help page of `git checkout`

Answer (score 0):

git checkout <commit_id>